# Problems with tetrachoric correlation matrix for IRT / Rasch test of unidimensionality

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, missing-data

We are scaling a Raschmodell and, since we developed a new adaptive test, we want to test our data for unidimensionality. 
It is developed to be used for measuring economic competencies.
There is 
one basic testlet and, based on the results, 

three difficulty-differentiated subtestlets.

So we made 

1. a data object including the binary data

```
test1 <- as.data.frame(eRm::sim.rasch(100, 10))
test2 <- as.data.frame(eRm::sim.rasch(100, 6))
test2[seq(6, nrow(test2),6),seq(3, ncol(test2),2)]<-NA # V3 and V5: every 6th value <- NA
test2[seq(3, nrow(test2),3),seq(1, ncol(test2),4)]<-NA # V1 and V5: every 3th value <- NA
test2[seq(2, nrow(test2),3),seq(2, ncol(test2),4)]<-NA # V2 and V6: every 3th value <-NA
test <- cbind(test1, test2)
```

The original data set is looking like this, but...

2. tried to compute a tetrachoric correlation Matrix

```
dat.tetra <- psych::tetrachoric(test, y=NULL, na.rm=T, weight=NULL, delete=TRUE)
dat.tetra.rho<-as.data.frame(dat.tetra$rho)
```

but it doesn`t work with the original data!!!

and

3. further, to compute a factoranalysis.

The Problem is that R (perhaps) is not able to compute the tetrachoric correlation Matrix for the adaptive test.
So I tried different versions with just parts of our items. 
When I just use the data from the Basic Testlet + the items from the Subtestlets overlapping for all 3 Groups, then R is able to compute the correlation Matrix.

But, of course, I want to include all items to see if the data is unidimensional.

The error for the complete data object is:

```
For i = 30 j = 16  A cell entry of 0 was replaced with correct = 0.5. Check your data!
Error in tet[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

If anyone has a good idea for a trick to solve this problem, I`d be glad!

Data:
N=2333
Items=59
  Basic=21
 easy, medium, difficult= 21, 21, 21 (with 20 for min. 2 Groups per item)

Comment: (1) Are you sure you have the most recent version of psych? Works here, just throwing a warning (note that the option "global" is TRUE by default, see [psych manual (as today: v 1.9.6)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf#page.350)); (2) Note that the as.data.frame-command fails due to duplicate colnames since psych borrows the names from the data set without consistency check -- and the test data have duplicated colnames; (3) you can try sirt::tetrachoric2 but results should be equivalent.